# does not contain an export named

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import a simple component into my React. I'm having trouble locating this component.

I'm getting the following error while importing component

> ./src/App.js 61:28-32 './componentes/Menu' does not contain an export
>   named 'Menu'.

This is my simple component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Menu extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Button bsStyle="danger">Hello World Dangerhahahah</Button>
          </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I'm calling it as follows in my App.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { Menu } from './componentes/Menu';

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <Button bsStyle="danger">Take this action</Button>
        <div className="App">

          <div className="bs-header" id="content">
            <div className="container">
              <h1>Template Changelog</h1>
              <p>Lists all changes to the HTML template files</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Menu.js` you are using `export default` which creates a export entry named `default` regardless what is the name of class

You should either:

1. Use `import Menu from './components/Menu';` in `App.js`
2. Use `export class Menu extends Component` in `Menu.js`

Answer (score 6):

It's because you're trying to destructure the exported default component from the file.

Just remove the brackets around the `Menu` from the import statement in the App component so `import { Menu } from './componentes/Menu';` becomes `import Menu from './componentes/Menu';`

Answer (score 1):

try changing `import { Menu } from './componentes/Menu';` to `import Menu from './componentes/Menu';`

Comment: If I remove brackets then how can we use more then?  import { Menu, Footer } from './componentes/Menu'; is it correct?