# GitHub.js does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, github-api

I am trying to use GitHub.js on a Chrome/Firefox extension and I have some issues.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/static/GitHub.bundle.js'
>   does not  provide an export named 'default'

I've found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744226/does-not-contain-an-export-named) but I still doesn't work. The authors of 99% of javascript give for granted that the basics are know, but either I don't know them or there is a subtle issue/bug I don't see.

My code is simple:

```
<html>
  <body id="mybody"> 
    <button id="mybutton" >Click me</button>
    <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and popup.js:

```
//import GitHub from './GitHub.bundle.js';
import * as GitHub from './GitHub.bundle.js';
function onWindowLoad() {
}
window.onload = onWindowLoad;
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", clickme); 

function clickme() {
    var github = new GitHub({
        username: 'USER',
        password: 'PASS',
        auth: 'basic'
    });
}
```

it does stop immediately. it doesn't matter what I have after that. What am I doing wrong? It shouldn't work even as a standalone page.

Note that I have to use .js  or I get a "file not found".

Library: https://github.com/github-tools/github

Comment: I don't see any `export` **statements** in their js package, only common stuff via require() and friends, so my guess would be their first official example is for something else. Remove `type="module"`, add a html script tag for GitHub.bundle.js, remove import statement. Done.

Comment: @wOxxOm If you write an answer I'm going to accept it. I also had to add underscore.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to remove the include and add the .js file and its depencies on the html file. Note that it's not really clear if you read github.js' site.

```
<html>
   <body id="mybody"> 
     <button id="mybutton" >Click me</button>
     <script src="GitHub.bundle.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="underscore-min.js"></script> 
     <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. I'm currently trying to solve a similar problem, but "put it all in html" is not an adequate solution.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a trick to do so:

Try :

```js
import * as GitHub from '/static/GitHub.bundle.js';
```

Comment: Yes it works! Now the next issue is that GitHub is not a constructor. The code is copied straight from the github repo of the library (apart for the include..) I suppose this trick is  not 100% correct

Comment: You will have to provide more code so we can help you.

Comment: I suspect GitHub.js does not work in browser, but the documentation doesn't say anything about that. 100% of the examples I've found do not mention how to use it in a webpage.